# Trying to link my javascript to a button

Tags: javascript, css

I'm new to JavaScript and i'm trying to figure out how to link the button I have to my function. The code is randomiser of sorts so essentially I'm trying to connect the button to my code so that you can click through the different items in a random order.

I just can't seem to get it working after trying a ton of different things.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="card fade-in">
        <p id="randomStrategy"></p>

        <script>

        // Establish a variable, which pulls from an array.

        var selectStrategy = [

        "Abandon desire",
        "Abandon normal instructions",
        "Accept advice",
        "Adding on",
        "A line has two sides",
        "Always the first steps",
        "Ask people to work against their better judgement",
        "Ask your body",
        "Be dirty",
        "Be extravagant",
        "Be less critical",
        "Breathe more deeply",
        "Bridges -build -burn",
        "Change ambiguities to specifics",
        "Change nothing and continue consistently",
        "Change specifics to ambiguities",
        "Consider transitions",
        "Courage!",
        "Cut a vital connection",
        "Decorate, decorate",
        "Destroy nothing; destroy the most important thing",
        "Discard an axiom",
        "Disciplined self-indulgence",
        "Discover your formulas and abandon them",
        "Display your talent",
        "Distort time",
        "Do nothing for as long as possible",
        "Don’t avoid what is easy",
        "Don’t break the silence",
        "Don’t stress one thing more than another",
        "Do something boring",
        "Do something sudden, destructive and unpredictable",
        "Do the last thing first",
        "Do the words need changing?",
        "Emphasise differences",
        "Emphasise the flaws",
        "Faced with a choice, do both (From Dieter Rot.)",
        "Find a safe part and use it as an anchor",
        "Give the game away",
        "Give way to your worst impulse",
        "Go outside. Shut the door.",
        "Go to an extreme, come part way back",
        "How would someone else do it?",
        "How would you have done it?",
        "In total darkness, or in a very large room, very quietly",
        "Is it finished?",
        "Is something missing?",
        "Is the style right?",
        "It is simply a matter or work",
        "Just carry on",
        "Listen to the quiet voice",
        "Look at the order in which you do things",
        "Magnify the most difficult details",
        "Make it more sensual",
        "Make what’s perfect more human",
        "Move towards the unimportant",
        "Not building a wall; making a brick",
        "Once the search has begun, something will be found",
        "Only a part, not the whole",
        "Only one element of each kind",
        "Openly resist change",
        "Pae White’s non-blank graphic metacard",
        "Question the heroic approach",
        "Remember quiet evenings",
        "Remove a restriction",
        "Repetition is a form of change",
        "Retrace your steps",
        "Reverse",
        "Simple Subtraction",
        "Slow preparation, fast execution",
        "State the problem as clearly as possible",
        "Take a break",
        "Take away the important parts",
        "The inconsistency principle",
        "The most easily forgotten thing is the most important",
        "Think -inside the work -outside the work",
        "Tidy up",
        "Try faking it (From Stewart Brand.)",
        "Turn it upside down",
        "Use an old idea",
        "Use cliches",
        "Use filters",
        "Use something nearby as a model",
        "Use ‘unqualified’ people",
        "Use your own ideas",
        "Voice your suspicions",
        "Water",
        "What context would look right?",
        "What is the simplest solution?",
        "What mistakes did you make last time?",
        "What to increase? What to reduce? What to maintain?",
        "What were you really thinking about just now?",
        "What wouldn’t you do?",
        "What would your closest friend do?",
        "When is it for?",
        "Where is the edge?",
        "Which parts can be grouped?",
        "Work at a different speed",
        "Would anyone want it?",
        "Your mistake was a hidden intention",
        "Use fewer notes",
        "Use filters",
        "Use ‘unqualified’ people",
        "Water",
        "What are you really thinking about just now? Incorporate",
        "What is the reality of the situation?",
        "What mistakes did you make last time?",
        "What would your closest friend do?",
        "What wouldn’t you do?",
        "Work at a different speed",
        "You are an engineer",
        "You can only make one dot at a time",
        "You don’t have to be ashamed of using your own ideas",
        // The following is where the randomness magic happens. 
        ];
        var pickAStrategy = function () {
        var randomStrategy = selectStrategy[Math.floor(Math.random() * selectStrategy.length)];
        return randomStrategy;
        };
        // This writes the strategy to the page.

        document.getElementById("randomStrategy").innerHTML = pickAStrategy();
        </script>

        <INPUT TYPE=BUTTON VALUE="Click Me" onClick="pickAStrategy(document.randomStrategy);" id="button"></INPUT>

    </div> <!-- /card -->
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Comment: Is it because your `document.getElementById...` is outside your function? Wrap that inside another function and call it from your button, maybe?

Comment: Put your javascript code after `<input>` tag. Or better after all html code

Comment: @ranveer Nope, the function variable and the set are in the same context. It's because the `onClick` event isn't right - `pickAStrategy()` takes no params, and the `onClick` does nothing with its result. It should be `onClick="this.innerHTML = pickAStrategy();"` Also, your JS should probably be at the *end* of the body.

Comment: @Santi the `document.....innerHTML` seems to be outside the function scope. What you're saying is correct, I just prefer using functions instead of long statements inside my HTML.

Comment: _"Or better after all html code"_ ... or even better, put the code in a completely separate `.js` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're returning a value, but not assigning the returned value to any DOM element.  Basically, you have to have your function change the actual DOM with  `document.getElementById("randomStrategy").innerHTML = randomStrategy;`.  I also made that particular DOM element return a placeholder value before you click the button, but you can change that behavior.

Also, your `onClick="pickAStrategy()"` shouldn't take any parameters.

Try this:

```js
        // Establish a variable, which pulls from an array.

        var selectStrategy = [

        "Abandon desire",
        "Abandon normal instructions",
        "Accept advice",
        "Adding on",
        "A line has two sides",
        "Always the first steps",
        "Ask people to work against their better judgement",
        "Ask your body",
        "Be dirty",
        "Be extravagant",
        "Be less critical",
        "Breathe more deeply",
        "Bridges -build -burn",
        "Change ambiguities to specifics",
        "Change nothing and continue consistently",
        "Change specifics to ambiguities",
        "Consider transitions",
        "Courage!",
        "Cut a vital connection",
        "Decorate, decorate",
        "Destroy nothing; destroy the most important thing",
        "Discard an axiom",
        "Disciplined self-indulgence",
        "Discover your formulas and abandon them",
        "Display your talent",
        "Distort time",
        "Do nothing for as long as possible",
        "Don’t avoid what is easy",
        "Don’t break the silence",
        "Don’t stress one thing more than another",
        "Do something boring",
        "Do something sudden, destructive and unpredictable",
        "Do the last thing first",
        "Do the words need changing?",
        "Emphasise differences",
        "Emphasise the flaws",
        "Faced with a choice, do both (From Dieter Rot.)",
        "Find a safe part and use it as an anchor",
        "Give the game away",
        "Give way to your worst impulse",
        "Go outside. Shut the door.",
        "Go to an extreme, come part way back",
        "How would someone else do it?",
        "How would you have done it?",
        "In total darkness, or in a very large room, very quietly",
        "Is it finished?",
        "Is something missing?",
        "Is the style right?",
        "It is simply a matter or work",
        "Just carry on",
        "Listen to the quiet voice",
        "Look at the order in which you do things",
        "Magnify the most difficult details",
        "Make it more sensual",
        "Make what’s perfect more human",
        "Move towards the unimportant",
        "Not building a wall; making a brick",
        "Once the search has begun, something will be found",
        "Only a part, not the whole",
        "Only one element of each kind",
        "Openly resist change",
        "Pae White’s non-blank graphic metacard",
        "Question the heroic approach",
        "Remember quiet evenings",
        "Remove a restriction",
        "Repetition is a form of change",
        "Retrace your steps",
        "Reverse",
        "Simple Subtraction",
        "Slow preparation, fast execution",
        "State the problem as clearly as possible",
        "Take a break",
        "Take away the important parts",
        "The inconsistency principle",
        "The most easily forgotten thing is the most important",
        "Think -inside the work -outside the work",
        "Tidy up",
        "Try faking it (From Stewart Brand.)",
        "Turn it upside down",
        "Use an old idea",
        "Use cliches",
        "Use filters",
        "Use something nearby as a model",
        "Use ‘unqualified’ people",
        "Use your own ideas",
        "Voice your suspicions",
        "Water",
        "What context would look right?",
        "What is the simplest solution?",
        "What mistakes did you make last time?",
        "What to increase? What to reduce? What to maintain?",
        "What were you really thinking about just now?",
        "What wouldn’t you do?",
        "What would your closest friend do?",
        "When is it for?",
        "Where is the edge?",
        "Which parts can be grouped?",
        "Work at a different speed",
        "Would anyone want it?",
        "Your mistake was a hidden intention",
        "Use fewer notes",
        "Use filters",
        "Use ‘unqualified’ people",
        "Water",
        "What are you really thinking about just now? Incorporate",
        "What is the reality of the situation?",
        "What mistakes did you make last time?",
        "What would your closest friend do?",
        "What wouldn’t you do?",
        "Work at a different speed",
        "You are an engineer",
        "You can only make one dot at a time",
        "You don’t have to be ashamed of using your own ideas",
        // The following is where the randomness magic happens. 
        ];
        var pickAStrategy = function () {
        var randomStrategy = selectStrategy[Math.floor(Math.random() * selectStrategy.length)];
        
        document.getElementById("randomStrategy").innerHTML = randomStrategy;

        };
        // This writes the strategy to the page.

        document.getElementById("randomStrategy").innerHTML = "some placeholder";
```

```html
    <div class="container">
    <div class="card fade-in">
        <p id="randomStrategy"></p>
        
            <INPUT TYPE=BUTTON VALUE="Click Me" onClick="pickAStrategy();" id="button"></INPUT>
    </div> <!-- /card -->
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Too slow on my answer - but demonstrating what's in the comments and in the other answers, such as istrupin's *"onClick="pickAStrategy() shouldn't take any parameters."*, and applying some better practices, I came up with this.
I've also renamed some things so the distinctions between names are easier to see.

First, simplify your page structure — get the code out of it (separation of concerns)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card fade-in">
        <p id="randomStrategy"></p>
        <input type="button" id="pickrandom" value="Click Me">
    </div> <!-- /card -->
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Notice there is no `onClick=` on the button. Better practice is to use the code itself to *attach* a handler for the event, like

```
document.getElementById('pickrandom').addEventListener('click', pickAStrategy);
```

The `pickAStrategy` function can set the contents of `p id="randomStrategy"` itself, so doesn't need to return anything.  This gives the following script block, which you would put at the *end* of your page markup. (Until you learn to attach code when the "DOM is ready")

```
<script>
document.getElementById('pickrandom').addEventListener('click', pickAStrategy);

function pickAStrategy()
{
    var chosenStrategy = strategies[Math.floor(Math.random() * strategies.length)];
    //console.log('chosen: ' + chosenStrategy);
    document.getElementById('randomStrategy').innerHTML = chosenStrategy;
}

var strategies = [ ... ];
</script>
```

Putting this all together, and adding some style so you can see where the randomStrategy is before it gets filled in, give this code [as seen in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/xcrkkc73/):

```
<style>
p#randomStrategy {
    min-height: 14px;
    min-width: 23px;
    border: 1px dotted green;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="card fade-in">
        <p id="randomStrategy"></p>
        <input type="button" id="pickrandom" value="Click Me">
    </div> <!-- /card -->
</div> <!-- /container -->


<script>
document.getElementById('pickrandom').addEventListener('click', pickAStrategy);

function pickAStrategy()
{
    var chosenStrategy = strategies[Math.floor(Math.random() * strategies.length)];
    //console.log('chosen: ' + chosenStrategy);
    document.getElementById('randomStrategy').innerHTML = chosenStrategy;
}

var strategies = [
    "Abandon desire",
    "Abandon normal instructions",
    "Accept advice",
    "Adding on",
    "A line has two sides",
    "Always the first steps",
    "Ask people to work against their better judgement",
    "Ask your body",
    "Be dirty",
    "Be extravagant",
    "Be less critical",
    "Breathe more deeply",
    "Bridges -build -burn",
    "Change ambiguities to specifics",
    "Change nothing and continue consistently",
    "Change specifics to ambiguities",
    "Consider transitions",
    "Courage!",
    "Cut a vital connection",
    "Decorate, decorate",
    "Destroy nothing; destroy the most important thing",
    "Discard an axiom",
    "Disciplined self-indulgence",
    "Discover your formulas and abandon them",
    "Display your talent",
    "Distort time",
    "Do nothing for as long as possible",
    "Don’t avoid what is easy",
    "Don’t break the silence",
    "Don’t stress one thing more than another",
    "Do something boring",
    "Do something sudden, destructive and unpredictable",
    "Do the last thing first",
    "Do the words need changing?",
    "Emphasise differences",
    "Emphasise the flaws",
    "Faced with a choice, do both (From Dieter Rot.)",
    "Find a safe part and use it as an anchor",
    "Give the game away",
    "Give way to your worst impulse",
    "Go outside. Shut the door.",
    "Go to an extreme, come part way back",
    "How would someone else do it?",
    "How would you have done it?",
    "In total darkness, or in a very large room, very quietly",
    "Is it finished?",
    "Is something missing?",
    "Is the style right?",
    "It is simply a matter or work",
    "Just carry on",
    "Listen to the quiet voice",
    "Look at the order in which you do things",
    "Magnify the most difficult details",
    "Make it more sensual",
    "Make what’s perfect more human",
    "Move towards the unimportant",
    "Not building a wall; making a brick",
    "Once the search has begun, something will be found",
    "Only a part, not the whole",
    "Only one element of each kind",
    "Openly resist change",
    "Pae White’s non-blank graphic metacard",
    "Question the heroic approach",
    "Remember quiet evenings",
    "Remove a restriction",
    "Repetition is a form of change",
    "Retrace your steps",
    "Reverse",
    "Simple Subtraction",
    "Slow preparation, fast execution",
    "State the problem as clearly as possible",
    "Take a break",
    "Take away the important parts",
    "The inconsistency principle",
    "The most easily forgotten thing is the most important",
    "Think -inside the work -outside the work",
    "Tidy up",
    "Try faking it (From Stewart Brand.)",
    "Turn it upside down",
    "Use an old idea",
    "Use cliches",
    "Use filters",
    "Use something nearby as a model",
    "Use ‘unqualified’ people",
    "Use your own ideas",
    "Voice your suspicions",
    "Water",
    "What context would look right?",
    "What is the simplest solution?",
    "What mistakes did you make last time?",
    "What to increase? What to reduce? What to maintain?",
    "What were you really thinking about just now?",
    "What wouldn’t you do?",
    "What would your closest friend do?",
    "When is it for?",
    "Where is the edge?",
    "Which parts can be grouped?",
    "Work at a different speed",
    "Would anyone want it?",
    "Your mistake was a hidden intention",
    "Use fewer notes",
    "Use filters",
    "Use ‘unqualified’ people",
    "Water",
    "What are you really thinking about just now? Incorporate",
    "What is the reality of the situation?",
    "What mistakes did you make last time?",
    "What would your closest friend do?",
    "What wouldn’t you do?",
    "Work at a different speed",
    "You are an engineer",
    "You can only make one dot at a time",
    "You don’t have to be ashamed of using your own ideas",
    // The following is where the randomness magic happens. 
    ];
</script>
```

Comment: That was a spectacular answer thank you, really disappointing I can only mark one of you as the most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

put your code that changes the text into the function itself

```
var pickAStrategy = function pickAStrategy() {
  var randomStrategy = selectStrategy[Math.floor(Math.random() * selectStrategy.length)];
  document.getElementById("randomStrategy").innerHTML = randomStrategy; //< THIS
};
```

```js
// Establish a variable, which pulls from an array.

var selectStrategy = [

  "Abandon desire",
  "Abandon normal instructions",
  "Accept advice",
  "Adding on",
  "A line has two sides",
  "Always the first steps",
  "Ask people to work against their better judgement",
  "Ask your body",
  "Be dirty",
  "Be extravagant",
  "Be less critical",
  "Breathe more deeply",
  "Bridges -build -burn",
  "Change ambiguities to specifics",
  "Change nothing and continue consistently",
  "Change specifics to ambiguities",
  "Consider transitions",
  "Courage!",
  "Cut a vital connection",
  "Decorate, decorate",
  "Destroy nothing; destroy the most important thing",
  "Discard an axiom",
  "Disciplined self-indulgence",
  "Discover your formulas and abandon them",
  "Display your talent",
  "Distort time",
  "Do nothing for as long as possible",
  "Don’t avoid what is easy",
  "Don’t break the silence",
  "Don’t stress one thing more than another",
  "Do something boring",
  "Do something sudden, destructive and unpredictable",
  "Do the last thing first",
  "Do the words need changing?",
  "Emphasise differences",
  "Emphasise the flaws",
  "Faced with a choice, do both (From Dieter Rot.)",
  "Find a safe part and use it as an anchor",
  "Give the game away",
  "Give way to your worst impulse",
  "Go outside. Shut the door.",
  "Go to an extreme, come part way back",
  "How would someone else do it?",
  "How would you have done it?",
  "In total darkness, or in a very large room, very quietly",
  "Is it finished?",
  "Is something missing?",
  "Is the style right?",
  "It is simply a matter or work",
  "Just carry on",
  "Listen to the quiet voice",
  "Look at the order in which you do things",
  "Magnify the most difficult details",
  "Make it more sensual",
  "Make what’s perfect more human",
  "Move towards the unimportant",
  "Not building a wall; making a brick",
  "Once the search has begun, something will be found",
  "Only a part, not the whole",
  "Only one element of each kind",
  "Openly resist change",
  "Pae White’s non-blank graphic metacard",
  "Question the heroic approach",
  "Remember quiet evenings",
  "Remove a restriction",
  "Repetition is a form of change",
  "Retrace your steps",
  "Reverse",
  "Simple Subtraction",
  "Slow preparation, fast execution",
  "State the problem as clearly as possible",
  "Take a break",
  "Take away the important parts",
  "The inconsistency principle",
  "The most easily forgotten thing is the most important",
  "Think -inside the work -outside the work",
  "Tidy up",
  "Try faking it (From Stewart Brand.)",
  "Turn it upside down",
  "Use an old idea",
  "Use cliches",
  "Use filters",
  "Use something nearby as a model",
  "Use ‘unqualified’ people",
  "Use your own ideas",
  "Voice your suspicions",
  "Water",
  "What context would look right?",
  "What is the simplest solution?",
  "What mistakes did you make last time?",
  "What to increase? What to reduce? What to maintain?",
  "What were you really thinking about just now?",
  "What wouldn’t you do?",
  "What would your closest friend do?",
  "When is it for?",
  "Where is the edge?",
  "Which parts can be grouped?",
  "Work at a different speed",
  "Would anyone want it?",
  "Your mistake was a hidden intention",
  "Use fewer notes",
  "Use filters",
  "Use ‘unqualified’ people",
  "Water",
  "What are you really thinking about just now? Incorporate",
  "What is the reality of the situation?",
  "What mistakes did you make last time?",
  "What would your closest friend do?",
  "What wouldn’t you do?",
  "Work at a different speed",
  "You are an engineer",
  "You can only make one dot at a time",
  "You don’t have to be ashamed of using your own ideas",
  // The following is where the randomness magic happens. 
];

var pickAStrategy = function pickAStrategy() {
  var randomStrategy = selectStrategy[Math.floor(Math.random() * selectStrategy.length)];
  document.getElementById("randomStrategy").innerHTML = randomStrategy;
};
// This writes the strategy to the page.
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="card fade-in">
        <p id="randomStrategy"></p>

        <INPUT TYPE=BUTTON VALUE="Click Me" onClick="pickAStrategy();" id="button"></INPUT>

    </div> <!-- /card -->
</div> <!-- /container -->
```